Citing references from another tex file and printing in another file
so I'm having some issue to print biblio where I want lol.
I want the tex file to appear in that oder:
\include{introduction}         
\include{conclusion}            
\include{biblio}

I have a biblio.tex file to print my bibliography from biblio.bib
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliographie}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliographie}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}  
\bibliography{biblio}
\nocite{} 

I want to cite in the introduction.tex file the biblio from biblio.bib and print it where I want this to be after concusion.tex and not in the introduction.tex file.
Thanks for your help !

Welcome to TeX.SE!
